# Quantiling column in R dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that I generated like so..

```
df = data.frame(
    Age = sample(18:98, 1000, replace = TRUE)
)
```

I want to create a new column that buckets the Age column based on the quantiles (25%, 50%, 75%. This can be done like so:

```
> quantile(df$Age, probs = c(0.25,0.5,0.75))
25% 50% 75% 
 39  58  78
```

Example output would look like so

```
Age Age_Bucket
19  25%
26  25%
87  75%
54  25%
20  25%
66  50%
```

How exactly can I do this in dplyr?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case_when`

```r
q <- quantile(df$Age, probs = c(0.25,0.5,0.75))

df %>% 
  mutate(Age_Bucket = case_when(
    Age < q[1] ~ "25%",
    between(Age, q[1], q[3]) ~ "50%", 
    Age > q[3] ~ "75%"
  ))
```

Comment: Is there anyway to make this more dynamic? As in do this for every continuous variable ?

Comment: Maybe using `mutate(across(is.numeric, <>))` somehow?